# Bootstrap Navbar Brand left, collapsible icons in center, and single item right

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, navbar

I've been trying to do this for to days now without any complete result, I've been trying codes from another questions made here and nothing. I want my navbar-brand to be in the left, some icons in the center and one icon in the right, I want all of them to be collapsable. I tried everything but the flexbox didn't work for me on the collapsable div, the only thing I could do and is the most approachable to my goal is this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-bee navbar-bee justify-content-between" role="navegador">
<a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
<button class="navbar-toggler ml-auto" type="button" data-target="#navegador" data-toggle="collapse" aria-label="Expandir navegador" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
<div class="navbar-nav">
    <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Comprar" class="d-none d-lg-block nav-item nav-link rounded" href="#"><span class="far fa-handshake icon-nav"></span></a>
    <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Vender" class="d-none d-lg-block nav-item nav-link rounded" href="#"><span class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd icon-nav"></span></a>
    <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mi carrito" class="d-none d-lg-block nav-item nav-link rounded" href="#"><span class="fas fa-shopping-cart icon-nav"></span></a>
</div>
<div class="navbar-nav">
    <form id="form-iSesion" action="procesos.php" method="POST">
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Entrar o registrarse" id="iSesion" class="d-none d-lg-block nav-item nav-link rounded" href="#"><span class="fas fa-user icon-nav"></span></a>
        <input type="hidden" name="menu" value="1">
    </form>
</div>
<!--<div class="collapse navbar-collapse bg-primary" id="navegador">
    <div class="navbar-nav">
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Comprar" class="d-md-block d-lg-none nav-item nav-link rounded" href="#"><span class="far fa-handshake icon-nav"></span></a>
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Vender" class="nav-item nav-link rounded" href="#"><span class="d-md-block d-lg-none fas fa-hand-holding-usd icon-nav"></span></a>
        <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mi carrito" class="d-md-block d-lg-none nav-item nav-link rounded" href="#"><span class="fas fa-shopping-cart icon-nav"></span></a>
        <form id="form-iSesion" action="procesos.php" method="POST">
            <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Entrar o registrarse" id="iSesion" class="d-md-block d-lg-none nav-item nav-link rounded" href="#"><span class="fas fa-user icon-nav"></span></a>
            <input type="hidden" name="menu" value="1">
        </form>
    </div>
</div>-->
</nav>
```

With this result:

[Full display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsze1.png)

[Responsive behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KApbg.png)

But once I active the collapsable navbar, everything get disordered again because that container is occupying a lot of space and anything that I've tried fix it

[Disordered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuHXk.png)

If I add a background you can see how much space it's occupying

[collapsable with background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xyrwX.png)

Sincerely I don't know what else try, this is making me crazy.

EDIT: ZimSystem solution works, but there's a problem. When the items collapse, every one of them is occupying an entire row. I want a display-inline for them when the menu collapses, an option would be to display all of them horizontally

Comment: What Bootstrap version are you using?

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu 4.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different ways using Bootstrap 4, but the simplest I think is to separate the `navbar-collapse`, give each Navbar section a defined width (using `w-*`), and then using the toggler to toggle both `navbar-collapse`.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-light navbar-light" role="navegador">
    <a class="navbar-brand w-25" href="#">Brand</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-target=".navbar-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" aria-label="Expandir navegador" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-50" id="navegador">
        <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto justify-content-center">
            <a data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Comprar" class="nav-item nav-link rounded" href="#"><span class="far fa-handshake icon-nav"></span></a>
            <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Vender" class="nav-item nav-link rounded" href="#"><span class="fas fa-hand-holding-usd icon-nav"></span></a>
            <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Mi carrito" class="nav-item nav-link rounded" href="#"><span class="fas fa-shopping-cart icon-nav"></span></a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse w-25" id="navegador2">
        <form id="form-iSesion" class="navbar-nav w-100  justify-content-end" action="procesos.php" method="POST">
            <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Entrar o registrarse" id="iSesion" class="nav-item nav-link rounded" href="#"><span class="fas fa-user icon-nav"></span></a>
            <input type="hidden" name="menu" value="1">
        </form>
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/FlImrjvZ0o

Comment: I partially tried this solution before but never thought on using defined width's. This works, thanks you.

Comment: Ok I just noticed out that when the menu collapse, and you display the items, every one of them is occupying a whole row

Comment: Yeah, that's the normal behavior. Your question didn't specify. Edit the question to clarify what the expectation is.

Comment: Ok, I just did it. Meanwhile I'm trying to solve it myself using css display properties, but no results

Comment: No, the elements are in the left

Comment: I want all of them in a single row, aligned to the left. Is it right to use display propertie in this case? I've been trying to target the resolution using @media but it doesn't seem to apply

Answer (score 0):

Here's a generic example, using Bootstrap v4, doing what you asked for. By default, the "center" menu is centered in the available space between logo and right menu. Note the `ml-auto mr-auto` classes on the middle element. They apply `auto` to left and right margins, centering it.

If you want a perfect center inside the browser, your only option is to **make the brand and the right menu have equal width in the flow of their parent**. One quick way is to take them out of their parent flow using `position:absolute`, but you'll need to position the logo and the right menu using `top/left/right` properties, and make sure they don't overlap with the center menu on any responsiveness interval.

But the simplest fix is to add a margin to the smaller one, so it gets to the size of the bigger one. In the example below I added a right margin of `22px` to the logo, which is the difference between its width and the right menus' width. (86.25 - 64.48):

```css
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  nav .navbar-brand {
    margin-right: 22px;
  }
}

/* YOU DON'T NEED THE CSS BELOW, I ADDED IT TO 
   SHOW THE MENU IS CENTERED */

/* marking the center of the nav */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  nav:after {
    width: 3px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: red;
    height: 100px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 100%;
  }
}


/* marking the center of the navbar-nav */

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .navbar-nav.ml-auto.mr-auto {
    position: relative;
  }
  .navbar-nav.ml-auto.mr-auto:after {
    width: 1px;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    background-color: black;
    height: 50px;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
          Dropdown
        </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
          <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="navbar-nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Some link</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Alernatively, this can be done via Javascript:

```js
(function($) {
  let centerMenu = function() {
    let $left = $('.navbar-brand'),
      $right = $('.navbar-nav', 'nav').last(),
      hasWidth = function(e) {
        return e.is('*') && e.width() > 0
      }

    if (hasWidth($left) && hasWidth($right) && $(window).width() > 992) {
      if ($left.width() > $right.width()) {
        $right.css({
          marginLeft: ($left.width() - $right.width()) + 'px'
        });
      } else {
        $left.css({
          marginRight: ($right.width() - $left.width()) + 'px'
        })
      }
      $(window).off('load resize', centerMenu);
    }
  };
  $(window).on('load resize', centerMenu);
})(jQuery)
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/LyL17ch3/).